# A word to describe how prepared someone is to vote

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a word—specifically, a noun—that would describe how prepared someone is to vote.

For example, saying Laura is more of a [word] than Leslie would imply that Laura has done more research into who she wants to vote for than Leslie has.

It wouldn't necessarily mean Laura is more smart, educated, or wealthy than Leslie.

Specifically, I'd rather not use the phrase "well-informed voter". For example, if I say Leslie is a well-informed voter, then it's not clear if Leslie is well-informed about everything in general, or just about voting. I'm trying to find a word that specifically refers to informedness on voting, but not necessarily anything else.

Does such a word exist? If not, is there a word I could create through which this meaning could easily be inferred?

Comment: "Laura is well-informed" means that she is generally knowledgable.  "Laura is a well-informed voter" means that she is knowledgable about the candidates and issues she will be voting on.  The term 'well-informed' modifies 'voter' - I doubt anyone will interpret it as "Laura is a generally well-informed person, who just happens to be a voter"

Comment: A well-informed voter doesn't usually mean they are well informed about other subjects, so it's unlikely to be confusing to the listener. However, to be a well-informed voter often coexists with other traits. That's just how the dough rises.

Comment: If you don't need a noun, I would use **prepared**, as in she's more prepared to vote. Would that work?

Answer (score 2):

**"politically involved"** seems to fit.

"Voters who are politically involved will certainly be better equipped to..."

> - In countries with higher income inequality the poor tend to be less [politically involved](https://ec.europa.eu/programmes/horizon2020/en/printpdf/965) – meaning their interests are not well represented in ...
> - Those who are [politically involved](https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/63876975/), meaning those with political positions, were asked another question. "Should the President resign or be ...

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few possible noun phrases: **political junky**, **news junky**, **policy wonk**.

From the Free Dictionary:

> [**junky**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/junky): someone who is so
>   ardently devoted to something that it resembles an addiction
>
> [**wonk**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wonk): a person who
>   studies a subject or issue in an excessively assiduous and thorough
>   manner

Your example:

> "Laura is more of a **political** junky than Leslie."
>
> "Laura is more of a **news junky** than Leslie."
>
> "Laura is more of a **policy wonk** than Leslie."

Each "would imply that Laura has done more research into who she wants to vote for than Leslie has."

Answer (score 0):

> Laura is more of a **conscious voter** than Leslie.

M-W:

> **[conscious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscious)**
>   *adjective*
>
> **7**:  done or acting with critical awareness : a conscious effort to do better

A usage example at www.populous.ca: [Be a conscious voter](http://populus.ca/2013/09/18/be-a-conscious-voter/)

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming preparedness to vote means being well-informed. That is not necessarily the case. In the last US elections, for example, the more politically involved people were among the progressive/left-leaning part of the voting public - the less likely they were to vote for Mrs. Clinton in the general elections. There was even a conscious "Bernie or Bust" campaign going on. And, indeed, traditional Democratic party voters exhibited low turn-out.

Another example is Palestinians in Israel. The more educated a person is and the more politically involved - the more likely they are to boycott the elections on political/conscientious grounds. Now, most of the Intelligentsia vote, but the boycott crowd is markedly more educated and involved on the average. AFAICT anyway.

So to play the devil's advocate I would suggest **gong-ho**, **eating it up** or **drinking the kool aid**. For a more positive spin on it - **inspired** or **enthused**.